# Echo binary (image) in Zend View

Tags: zend-framework

i want to echo an Image inside an Zend Framework View Script (files cant be read by user)

This works in Controller:

```
        $service = My_Service_Factory::getFileServer();
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        echo $service->getProfilePicture($user); // returns binary string
        exit;
```

But how to implement this for Zend View?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you assigning the binary data to a variable and echo'ing it in a view, but what's wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: was an failure in my brain :-) I want to add the pic inside an div , and now i understand that i need an controller action like "downloadPic" wich sets the header and echos the pic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also not sure why you'd want this in a view...

It makes the most sense to get the response object, and change the content type there, as well as set the body.

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    ->setBody($service->getProfilePicture($user))
                    ->sendResponse();
```